# Health-care and immigration within the EU

Tags: immigration, poland, health-care

So to speak, let's suppose that I am leaving Southern Europe (Greece), for Eastern Europe (Hungary/Poland).

Could the government of the latter have access to my past medical history by law, taking into account that I currently have a strong disability status, due to unnecessary psychiatric intervention?

Or I may as well start a new life altogether outside the European Union?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no EU-wide infrastructure of any kind to handle personal medical files. There are [plans to enable information sharing *upon explicit request* by the patient](http://ec.europa.eu/digital-agenda/en/news/eu-takes-major-step-improve-cross-border-care) but even that is not implemented.

Comment: Mental health might fall under law enforcement, seems to be mentioned in list of [data managed by SIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Information_System#Data_managed_by_the_SIS)

Comment: @vartec It depends what you mean with “law enforcement”, this refers to article 97 of the Schengen convention, so basically people who are missing. People are only listed there if they “need to be placed provisionally in a place of safety” (so basically hospitalized without consent, a pretty drastic measure) and not merely if they have been diagnosed with some psychiatric disorder. The information included is also very limited and certainly does not include medical history. Incidentally, the SIS would not be routinely queried if you don't cross an external border.

Comment: Now, if a person also had run-ins with the law, there are other mechanism to share criminal records, independently of any mental health diagnosis but that's a completely different question.